# Meta Marketing API: Reading Website URL from ads with Instagram or Facebook posts as Ad Creative

Tags: http, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to keep track of URLs used on boosted posts in my ad account. The Marketing API documentation lays out the ability to attach calls to action with an existing post as creative:

[Use Posts As Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/ads-api/guides/use-posts-as-ads)
"To create your ads, complete the process described on Instagram Ads API, Get Started up until Step 3: Create Ad Set. For Step 4: Provide Ad Creative and Create Ad, make the following changes:
If you would like, you can update the call_to_action field for your promotion. For example:

```
curl -i -X POST \ "https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT>/adcreatives ?     object_id=<PAGE_ID> &instagram_user_id=<IG_USER_ID> &source_instagram_media_id=<IG_ORGANIC_MEDIA_ID> &call_to_action="{'type':'LEARN_MORE','value':{'link': '<YOUR_LINK>'}} &access_token=<API_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Once you have provided your ad creative, create your ads. You also have the option of providing your creative as you create your ads —without having to separate the process in two steps."

My existing post ads return the following fields when using all the possible fields from the ad creative documentation:

```
['id', 'account_id', 'actor_id', 'body', 'call_to_action_type', 'effective_authorization_category', 'effective_instagram_media_id', 'effective_instagram_story_id', 'effective_object_story_id', 'enable_direct_install', 'enable_launch_instant_app', 'instagram_actor_id', 'instagram_permalink_url', 'instagram_user_id', 'name', 'object_story_id', 'object_type', 'url_tags']
```

When trying to read call_to_action specifically I get the following result:

```
Request failed with response code 400b'{"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (call_to_action) on node type (AdCreative)","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AT2EUKKQLVjVdl8jHUeNR9G"}}'
```

The field doesn't return anything with the ads edge either. Any help on how to return this field would be appreicated!